# Programmatically restarting a firefox extension

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am making a Firefox extension using Mozilla addons-sdk. I show a particular HTML page in a panel. Based on a certain event received, I want to reload the extension(and not just the page). Reload = re-run main.js as it does when browser restarts.

The problem with reloading just the HTML page is that, while the reload happens, the page-worker is still the old one and the events received during the time of reload aren't handled correctly. Corresponding to those events, you get the following error:

```
Timestamp: 4/11/13 12:34:20 PM
Error: ubp-install: An exception occurred.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/panel.js", line 273, in _onHide
    this._emit('hide');
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/deprecated/events.js", line 123, in _emit
    return this._emitOnObject.apply(this, args);
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/deprecated/events.js", line 153, in _emitOnObject
    listener.apply(targetObj, params);
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/ubp-install/lib/main.js", line 232, in 
type: 'Application_reload'
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/content/worker.js", line 369, in 
    emit: function () self._emitEventToContent(Array.slice(arguments))
  File "resource://onebutton-at-user043-dot-com/addon-sdk/lib/sdk/content/worker.js", line 404, in _emitEventToContent
    throw new Error(ERR_FROZEN);
Error: The page is currently hidden and can no longer be used until it is visible again.
```

In short, I need a way to reload a firefox extension.

Comment: Can you destroy the page-worker and create a new one? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-worker.html#destroy%28%29